# how do i enable google analytics on my nextjs application?

Tags: next.js, google-analytics

i made this GA component

```
import Script from 'next/script';

export const GA = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Script
        id="google-analytics-script"
        strategy="lazyOnload"
        src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS}`}
      />
      <Script
        id="google-analytics-config"
        strategy="lazyOnload"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());
          gtag('config', '${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS}', {
          page_path: window.location.pathname,
          });
          `,
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

and i put in to _app.tsx file

```
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import Favicon from 'react-favicon';
import '../../public/assets/fonts/styles.css';
import { GlobalStyles } from '../styles/global-styles';
import { AppThemeProvider } from 'contexts/ThemeContext';
import icon from '../../public/assets/images/logo.png';
import { GA } from 'components/GA';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <AppThemeProvider>
      <Favicon url={icon.src} />
      <GA />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <GlobalStyles />
    </AppThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

but my google analytics isn't receiving any data... what i'm doing wrong?

i already tried to change this component to my _document.tsx file but still not working

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, and there could be reasons outside of the scope of your question that you don't receive data, but I put a suggestion below based on the implementation in the Next docs. Thought it might be worth a look. Let me know.

First thing might be to ensure that `NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS` secret is set in production and double check that the full URL is correct.

For the script try replacing with the following. The docs show the GTM script code placed inside `<Script></Script>` passed in a string between `{}` and use a different order and loading strategy.

```
<Script id="google-analytics-config" strategy="afterInteractive">
  {`
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', '${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS}', {
          page_path: window.location.pathname,
          });
  `}
</Script>
<Script
  id="google-analytics-script"
  strategy="afterInteractive"
  src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS}`}
/>
```

### Docs

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-script-for-ga

Comment: i figure it out what i did wrong. i forget tht "www" after the https:// and my code are not working